# Git ignore except one file type

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a rule that ignores bin folder (build results):
`[Bb]in/`

I want git to still add all .txt files, even those in bin directory (but ignore everything else in that dir). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Bb]in/*
!*.txt
```

This pattern should find you an answer. If you prepend the negation(`!`) before a pattern, it is marked as not to be ignored irrespective of all the ignores above it.
Refer -  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore

Comment: Unfortunately, until Git has some reason that it has to scan the directory (such as at least one tracked file within it), if the directory itself is in the ignore file, Git won't bother to look *inside* that directory, and hence won't notice that `*.txt` files exist. The fix is easy though: instead of ignoring `[Bb]in/`, ignore `[Bb]in/*`, so that Git must look inside the directory to find `*`. Then the overrides from `!*.txt` can affect the filenames that Git has now looked-at.

Answer (score 0):

Cited from https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so ...